# Fill template of one class from another template class

Tags: c++, templates

If I have two classes:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
  ...
};

tempalte <typename T_Node, typename T>
struct NodeIterator
{
  T m_value;
};

NodeIterator<Node<int>, int>
```

can I deduce the template argument `T` from `T_Node` without the class `Node` explicitly creating a typedef like this:

```
// To make it clear, yes I know this works, but I had to typedef the type
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
  typedef T node_type;
  ...
};

template <typename T_Node>
struct NoteIterator
{
  typedef typename T_Node::node_type node_type;

  node_type m_value;
};

NodeIterator<Node<int> >
```

If not, is there a reason why I cannot do that (the compiler already knows about `T_Node` and the type `T` it took in) apart from *"the feature is just not there in C++"*? I ask this as usually there is a good reason for something simple (at least on the surface) like this missing from the language.

Comment: Have you tried it? What error did you get?

Comment: My sentence is a little ambiguous. The solution I presented works. I wanted to know if there is a solution where I do not have to `typedef` the type.

Comment: @Samaursa: You forgot `typename` in `  typedef T_Node::node_type node_type;`. See my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the typedef, that's not possible. The point is that the compiler has no idea that `T_Node` is itself an instantiation of a template. `Node<T>` is just a *type*, nothing more.

C++ knows three tiers of entities: values, types, and templates. `Node` is a template, and `Node<T>` is a type. When your class template accepts a *type* parameter, then you have no further way to inspect the nature of that type.

Pattern matching through partial specialization is the only way to extract such information, and you don't get around a bit of functional metaprogramming. Any sort of type inspection is usually referred to as a "type trait". It'll all boil down to the same thing, very similar to what you already suggested, but perhaps here's another, more generic way:

```
template <typename> struct ClassWithOneArg;

template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
struct ClassWithOneArg<C<T>>
{
  typedef T value_type;
};
```

Now you can say: `typedef typename ClassWithOneArg<T_Node>::value_type type;`.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont't you change the `NodeIterator` to something like that:

```
template <typename T>
struct NodeIterator
{
  typedef Node<T> node_type;

  node_type m_value;
};
```

this should allow you to create objects of the type `NodeIterator<int>`. I think this would be an elegant solution.
`

Comment: Because I don't want `NodeIterator` to know about `Node`

Comment: Why is that? Look at the STL, the iterators are even defined in their according containers, and thus share a pretty close relationship.

Comment: Also, with your proposed solution there would be another tight coupling of the two classes, since your `T_Node` is expected to have a `typedef` called `node_type`.

Comment: Right, which is why I asked is there a solution without using `typedef`. I don't want it to know because I have a few different Node types and I'll have to create an iterator for each node type. I also want to avoid polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What you've tried is almost correct, except that you forgot `typename`:

```
typedef typename T_Node::node_type node_type;
       //^^^^^^^ note this!
```

You need to write the keyword `typename` because the nested type `node_type` is a dependent *type*.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I misunderstood the question. Anyway, corrected it.

Comment: Ah yes, the infamous `typename` keyword :) I will correct it in my question (+1)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You need the typedef. C++ does not have any compile time reflection support, where this feature would fit in.

The reason why it is not in the language is simple: No one came up with a good proposal for such a feature in the standardization process. This is probably becasue such a feature is not trivial. Why you might be just happy with getting hands on the template parameters, there are lots of other places that would need to be considered to make the feature as a whole look "round".

You could work out such a proposal when intrested ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, but I don't think you should need to either.  Using typedefs for this is a well-established practice; look at the standard containers and their `value_type`, etc. typedefs.

You mentioned in a comment on another answer that you don't want `NodeIterator` to know about `Node`.  It doesn't have to know about `Node` specifically; it just requires that its template argument be *some* type that contains a `node_type` type within it.  That could be `Node` or it could be something else, and `NodeIterator` doesn't have to know or care.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you cannot do that in C++.  This is why STL iterator types contain those nested typedefs that you're trying to avoid.  Also, relying on those nested types is going to get you in trouble if you want to allow pointers to Nodes (which fit all the requirements for RandomAccessIterators).  You'll need to use traits classes if you want to include raw pointers to Nodes as node iterator types, since they cannot have nested types.